# How can I use the sumif function with criteria beeing exact text from another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, criteria, sumifs

Google sheets. So, I want to add cells that contains EXACT text from B3.

I use the function

=SUMIF ('Sheet2'!B:B, "* "&B3&"* ",'Sheet2'!D:D)

it works ok, but when the ('Sheet2'!B:B) contains text MOR it adds up. I want it to add up only cells containing exact matching cells that have MORNING.

Hope someone knows a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out. I used =SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet2'!B:B=B7),'Sheet2'!D:D)  Hope it is useful for other people too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove *

```
=SUMIF('Sheet2'!B:B, B3 ,'Sheet2'!D:D)
```

Comment: Yes! This works as well as my solution. Indeed, your formula is shorter, more simple. Thanks !